# rxjs : get duplicate http requests on the first set that I send

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6, rxjs-observables

I made this functionality, each iteration i have 7 requests that sent each environment.dashboard.frequency time,
but at the beginning, I see that i send 14 requests to the server instead of 7 :

```
let requests: Observable<ResourceResponse>[] = initRequests(this.durationService.resourceDataDuration)
    timer(0, environment.dashboard.frequency)
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.destroy),
        startWith(0),
        switchMap(() => forkJoin(requests))
      )
      .subscribe((responsesArr: ResourceResponse[]) => {
        this.updateBegin()
        for (const response of responsesArr) {
          this.durationService.resourceDurationHandler.setPresentedDataRanges(
            response,
            this.durationService.resourceDataDuration,
            this.durationService.resourcePresnetedDataDurations
          )
          this.updateMany(response.Resource, response.Response, true)
        }
        this.updateEnd()
        requests = initRequests(this.durationService.resourceDataDuration)
      })
```

Comment: Do you really need the startWith here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`timer(0, environment.dashboard.frequency)` -> `dueTime = 0` -> not need `startWith`